# implementing simple hadoop scheduler, how to submit hadoop job from external program?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I want to implement a simple hadoop scheduler in java. I am new with Hadoop so when looking at oozie code I am getting lost. I need a clean way to submit mapreduce job inside my code in the same way I am running it on the command line. For example, this command is used for caluclating PI on hadoop using the examples jar file provided with Cloudera.

```
bash-4.1$ /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar pi 2 1000
```

So I expect to find code that will take some configuration, jar file, main class and parameters for execution.

Answer (score 0):

With the following command:

```
hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar pi 10 100
```